# string auto splitting in each loop - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I have the following jquery code that is looping through the returned json data, for some reason is it splitting the suburb by a space when being assigned as the value but not as the text, I cannot work out why this is happening.

MY CODE

```
$.each(data , function( index, obj ) {
                    $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
                        var suburb = $.trim(value['mcdl01']);
                        var number = $.trim(value['mcmcu']);
                         $("#FeedbackBranchName").append("<option value=" + suburb + ">" + suburb + " (" + number + ")</option>");
                    });
                });
```

SAMPLE RETURNED RESULTS

```
<option **value="AIRLIE" beach=""**>AIRLIE BEACH (4440)</option>
<option value="ASHMORE">ASHMORE (4431)</option>
<option **value="BANYO" commercial=""**>BANYO COMMERCIAL (4432)</option>
<option value="BEENLEIGH">BEENLEIGH (4413)</option>
<option value="BERRIMAH">BERRIMAH (4453)</option>
<option **value="BOWEN" hills=""**>BOWEN HILLS (4433)</option>
```

Notice how for AIRLEE BEACH, BANYO COMMERICAL AND BOWN HILLS the second word has been separated out from the value attribute but it's fine at the text level.

Anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Thanks

Comment: If the value of an HTML attribute contains a space, the value has to be in quotation marks. Otherwise the browser does not know what is part of the value and what is an attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your attribute values is quotes so that part of it(after the space) is not considered as a new attribute.

```
$("#FeedbackBranchName").append("<option value='" + suburb + "'>" + suburb + " (" + number + ")</option>");
                                                ^_________________________________
```

Better use jquery element constructor.

```
 $("#FeedbackBranchName").append($('<option/>', {
    value: suburb,
    text: suburb + " (" + number + ")"
}));
```

Comment: +1 Was just about to suggest the second syntax you provided. Not sure why anyone would DV this answer.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Not sure... :( Yeah i was typing in the second syntax... :)

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted - it wasn't me. I don't see anything wrong with this answer, especially now that you've updated it to include the jQuery option.

Comment: @jcsanyi I undated it minutes ago right after adding the arrow mark for the first option... Got down voted after that i guess...

Comment: It was me, because your first suggestion is just a band aid, please make a small edit so that I can revert my vote.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for letting me know. I edited my answer.... i loved the term band aid... :)

Answer (score 2):

In general when creating new HTML elements, it's best to let jQuery do the proper escaping for you:

```
$.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
    var suburb = $.trim(value['mcdl01']),
    number = $.trim(value['mcmcu']);

    $("#FeedbackBranchName").append($("<option/>", {
        value: suburb,
        text: suburb + " (" + number + ")"
    }));
});
```

You could also use the [`Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option) constructor:

```
$("#FeedbackBranchName")
   .append(new Option(suburb + " (" + number + ")", suburb));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not including quotes around the `value` attributes.

The actual HTML being generated is this:

```
<option value=AIRLIE BEACH>AIRLIE BEACH (4440)</option>
```

Which is getting interpreted by the browser like this:

```
<option value="AIRLIE" BEACH="">AIRLIE BEACH (4440)</option>
```

To fix this, you can wrap the value in quotes like this:

```
$("#FeedbackBranchName")
    .append('<option value="' + suburb + '">' + suburb + " (" + number + ")</option>");
```

Or better yet, use jQuery to set the value instead of building the HTML as a string:

```
$("#FeedbackBranchName").append(
    $("<option />")
        .val(suburb)
        .text(suburb + ' (' + number + ')')
);
```